# Login Required when using AdminDirectory.users.Get in javascript

Tags: javascript, sdk, google-api

I am writing an application to list or update users using Javascript. I have enabled the relevant API's in dev console. This all works ok if I use AdminDirectory.Users.list, however when I try to get a single user via AdminDirectory.Users.get and pass the google ID as the key, I get Login Required.
I have tried to add option .viewType = "domain_public" but to no avail.

For now, Im going to re-write the local function that uses .get to get the user via list, but would like to know if anyone else has this problem or know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, Following some investigation, the issue is how the code is called. The list function works as Im calling this from a menu Item whereas the get Im calling from the onEdit. OnEdit trigger has LIMITED set in the auth_mode so it will not work.
I proved this by writing a function to call the get and then made a call to this new function from a menu item and it worked.
Would be nice if Google would allow security to be setup maybe in the dev console to allow onEdit to run for a given project with full access ? just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I tried to write a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to retrieve the users in our directory.  After reading Paul's comment, I checked and found that custom functions operate with same minimal permissions, so I also added a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) to load the users.

At risk of giving advice without testing it myself: for triggers, you'll need to use an event with an [`authMode` value of `FULL`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/auth-mode). 
 See the [Google Apps Script Event Objects guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).